# Connecting to database via ODBC

Tags: database, odbc, 32-bit, pyodbc

I have running a 32-bit software(Lexware) running on a 64-bit server that uses SQL Anywhere 12 database. Several clients a connecting via ODBC to this database.

After one employee updated the server one client stopped working correctly. PyOdbc gave the message that the architecture of the driver does not correspond the the one of Lexware.

It seems that I am using the 64-bit ODBC driver, which does not work with a 32-bit Lexware. So I tried to use the 32-bit ODBC driver. The client is using Windows7 64-bit.

1. I went to the 32-bit ODBC Data Sources
2. Clicked on Add
3. Chose "SQL Anywhere 12"-driver
4. Clicked Finish
5. Then an error messages appears: "The setup routines for SQL Anywhere 12 could   not be found. Install the driver again."
6. I click ok. Another message appears. "Error found: Component could not be found in the registry.
7. I then installed the whole sybase drivers again.

But I get the same error. I do not know what to do anymore. I also tried several other things. What I find curious is that everything worked before. All the other clients also work. Just this one does not. I need this to work for my company.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

Under `"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Wow6432Node/ODBC/ODBCINST.INI/SQL Anywhere 12"`

The Strings "Driver" and "Setup" were missing. I added the path to the 32-bit ODBC drivers. Now everything works again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the 32-bit version of the Lexware ODBC drivers. You also need to install the 32-bit version of the client you are using to query the databases.

You cannot mix 32 and 64 bit code in one process.

Comment: I know. The problem is that I have installed the 32 bit driver but when trying to create a new User-DSN I always get the error: "The setup routines for SQL Anywhere 12 could not be found. Install the driver again." and  "Error found: Component could not be found in the registry"

Comment: That sounds like it's not installed. Are you sure that SQL Anywhere 12 is installed with the 32bit version? The machine is saying it isn't.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. I downloaded the drivers from here: http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-35857. I then install the 64 and 32 bit versions. After that I try to create a new User-DSN, using the 32-bit ODBC console, which does not work. How can I verify that the 32 bit driver is installed?